# How to do I navigate to a fragment when I click on a cardview

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-cardview

I am practicing Kotlin, I'm trying to navigate to a fragment when I click on a `cardView`.

*Please show some patience and understaning I'm new, cos I don't even know how to ask this, even though I know what I want to do..*

I think I need to create a function like this:

```
private fun CardView.setOnClickListener(function: () -> Unit) {

}
```

But I don't know what argument I'll pass.
This is two of the CardView I want to be able to click:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/ways_teach_people_what_you_know"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/ways_show_people_how_to_do_things"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
```

And want to navigate those cardViews to these fragments;

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class WaysTeachPeopleWhatYouKnowFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_ways_teach_people_what_you_know) {

}


import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class WaysShowPeopleHowToDoThingsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_ways_show_people_how_to_do_things) {

}
```

I didn't add the `.xml` file of the fragments I want to navigate to, it's empty right now, but please if you need it I can add it.

Please I'd like to use `findViewByID` when referencing the CardView.

If I don't need to create a function, or you know another I can navigate to fragment when I click on the cardView, I'm more than happy to learn it.

I'd appreciate some sample code, And please make it easy for me to understand and understand so I can add the other cardView and fragments I want to navigate to.. Thanks for help in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using navController then
In Activity

```
CardView.setOnClickListener{
```

findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.your_destination_fragment)}

In Fragment

```
CardView.setOnClickListener{
```

findNavController().navigate(R.id.your_destination_fragment)}